# Query Azure Function invocations from C# Test project running in DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I'm looking for a way to query Azure Functions, or ApplicationInsights for all invocations made to a given function in an Azure Function Application.

I found that I can do this quite easily with the AZ cli, something like:

```
az monitor app-insights query --app "{AZURE_FUNCTION_NAME}" --resource-group "{RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}" --analytics "requests | where name == '{FUNCTION_NAME}' | top 1 by timestamp desc"
```

Is there any way I can do this in C#?

I actually am just interested in knowing if my function has run and if it is finished. Basically I want to know this so I can initiate my integration tests.

I've looked into the TelemetryClient but I can't really get it to work. If someone has an example using the TelemetryClient I'd gladly take a look at that as well. **But primarily, I am mainly looking for a way to check if my functions have run or not in the recent hour.**

Comment: Hi Jonathan, it is very convenient to use the Azure CLI task to run the Azure CLI command in azure pipeline. Can you share your reason for not using azure cli commands?

Comment: The verification is needed within a C# test project, since I'm actually integration testing within my devops pipeline. I could ofc run AZ cli and then initiate my tests but I found it a bit inconvenient because I would then have to initiate one test project, then run a task for az cli and then run the next test project.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does the answer from Peter help with the issue?

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT I haven't been able to test it out fully.. So far I cannot verify it because it isn't an answer to what I want to do but rather an example from Microsofts Documentation.. I understand though that I can't be spoiled here :) hehe.. But I can't really verify that I have my answer. How do I run the above query but using C# is basically all I'm wondering if you get what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TelemetryClient` can only be used to send telemetry. You cannot query any data with it.

You can either use the [Azure Monitor Query client library for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/monitor.query-readme?view=azure-dotnet) for that or leverage the [Log Analytics REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/)

Example using the client:

```cs
    var client = new LogsQueryClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
    string workspaceId = "XXX";
    var functionName = "FunctionName";

    var response = await client.QueryWorkspaceAsync(
        workspaceId,
        $"AppRequests | where Name == '{functionName}' | top 1 by TimeGenerated desc",
        new QueryTimeRange(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)));

    foreach (var rowData in response.Value.Table.Rows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{rowData}");
    }
```

You need to install the Azure.Identity and Azure.Monitor.Query packages for the code to run.

Example using the api:

```
GET https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/63613592-b6f7-4c3d-a390-22ba13102111/query?query=union * | where TimeGenerated > ago(1h) | summarize count() by Type, TenantId
```

**Do mind** that it can take some time between the moment the function has finished and the moment the telemetry appears in Azure Monitor.

Comment: I understand your answer and all and I have been trying to test it out but since I don't really know what to expect from your query in connection with the workspace id I'm using I don't really know if it works or not. (But I think it doesn't work tbh and it's some problem on my end)

However.. I am trying to run the query I mentioned. Do you know where I can find the documentation for that? Because I take it then I should use the TelemetryClient?

Comment: @JonathanHarr I've update the sample code to match your use case.

Comment: Yes! This was exactly what I was looking for. How come they specify AppRequests instead of just requests?

I also take it that I may have tried to query one step above the logs.. Do you know any good place to start and see how the hierarchy of loganalytics, workspace and monitor is structured so one would better understand where to query and how to query?